# Easy IIS7 Rewrite Redirect Question

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm just getting to grips with IIS7 redirect and having problems doing something that should be really simple:

I'd like to redirect all requests for domain.net/post and redirect to
domain.net/blog/post and keep the parameters so example:

www.domain.net/post/how-to-do-something.aspx -> www.domain.net/blog/post/how-to-do-something.aspx

Any ideas please!?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern could be

^post/(.*)$ or ^post/([a-z0-9-]*)$

and the URL rewrite

blog/post/{R:1}

(but I haven't tested yet)